# ¿Cómo puedo fusionar estas dos funciones de filtro a wp_list_pages en una sola?

Tags: php, wordpress

Tengo el siguiente problema.

Estoy utilizando la función `wp_list_pages()` dentro de una función propia para generar una lista de páginas "hija" de la página superior a la que actualmente está viendo el usuario. Hasta ahí todo bien, pero siendo que empleo Bootstrap para el diseño de la página, necesito que el output de esta función siga la siguiente estructura:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="" class="nav-link">Texto del link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="" class="nav-link">Texto del link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="" class="nav-link">Texto del link 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="" class="nav-link">Texto del link 4</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="" class="nav-link">Texto del link 5</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Para ello, es necesario reemplazar la asignación de clases que hace por default `wp_list_pages()` y aplicarle la clase "nav-item" a los elementos `<li>` y la clase "nav-link" a los elementos `<a>`.

Basándome en otras soluciones a problemas similares, decidí aprovecharme del hook que provee la función `wp_list_pages()` y aplicarle un filtro.

El problema es que me veo obligado a filtrar primero los item `<li>` y luego los item `<a>`, utilizando dos funciones diferentes. De lo contrario, me ha sido imposible retornar correctamente el resultado de la función.

```
add_filter('wp_list_pages', 'custom_class_item_list_child_pages');

function custom_class_item_list_child_pages($output) {
    return str_replace('<li ', "<li class=\"nav-item\" ", $output);
}

add_filter('wp_list_pages', 'custom_class_link_list_child_pages');

function custom_class_link_list_child_pages($output) {
    return str_replace('<a ', "<a class=\"nav-link\" ", $output);
}
```

Es posible de algún modo solucionar esto con una sola función en lugar de tener que utilizar dos de ellas? Cómo debería llevarlo adelante?

**EDITO:** Continuando la búsqueda de soluciones, además de la aportada más abajo llegué a la siguiente alternativa:

```
add_filter('wp_list_pages', 'custom_items_list_child_pages');

function custom_items_list_child_pages($output) {
    return str_replace( array('<li ','<a '), array('<li class="nav-item"', '<a class="nav-link" '), $output );
}
```

De esta forma, en lugar de utilizar varias `str_replace()`, utilizo como argumento de búsqueda un array y como argumento de reemplazo un array equivalente con los valores correspondientes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cada funcion hace un replace solamente, así que bastaría con aplicar dos veces en la misma funcion

```
add_filter('wp_list_pages', 'double_check');

function double_check($output){
    $first = str_replace('<li ', "<li class=\"nav-item\" ", $output);
    return str_replace('<a ', "<a class=\"nav-link\" ", $first);
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda! Como comentario adicional, pensando un poco más y leyendo otras aplicaciones de str_replace() llegué a otra forma de resolverlo utilizando un array para la búsqueda y un array correspondiente para el reemplazo. Voy a agregarlo como edición en la pregunta.